# Unserialize, serialize value of textarea

Tags: php

Anyone knows how to unserialize the serialize value of textarea.
Here is the value of my serialize text area.

```
a:69:{s:12:\"booking_code\";s:8:\"GE100013\";s:10:\"booking_id\";s:2:\"10\";s:10:\"package_id\";s:2:\"10\";s:12:\"package_days\";s:1:\"4\";s:13:\"extended_days\";s:1:\"0\";s:21:\"hotel_surcharge_final\";s:1:\"0\";s:20:\"room_surcharge_final\";s:1:\"0\";s:18:\"package_total_cost\";s:4:\"1820\";s:20:\"package_total_profit\";s:3:\"140\";s:21:\"package_total_payment\";s:4:\"1960\";s:23:\"package_total_surcharge\";s:1:\"0\";s:29:\"package_hotel_total_surcharge\";s:1:\"0\";s:29:\"package_room_total_surcharges\";s:1:\"0\";s:18:\"package_hotel_name\";a:1:{i:0;s:12:\"PICNIC HOTEL\";}
```

I want to unserialize this to the other form so when i pass this i unserialize the code but nothing happened.
Here is my unserialize code

```
print_r(unserialize($_POST['step_booking_serialized']));
```

The name of my textarea was step_booking_serialized.

Comment: You're doing it right.

Comment: but it has no result to display :'(

Comment: What is the data of this `print_r(unserialize($_POST['step_booking_serialized']));`?

Comment: a:69:{s:12:\"booking_code\";s:8:\"GE100013\";s:10:\"booking_id\";s:2:\"10\";s:10:\"package_id\";s:2:\"10\";s:12:\"package_days\";s:1:\"4\";s:13:\"extended_days\";s:1:\"0\";s:21:\"hotel_surcharge_final\";s:1:\"0\";s:20:\"room_surcharge_final\";s:1:\"0\";s:18:\"package_total_cost\";s:4:\"1820\";s:20:\"package_total_profit\";s:3:\"140\";s:21:\"package_total_payment\";s:4:\"1960\";s:23:\"package_total_surcharge\";s:1:\"0\";s:29:\"package_hotel_total_surcharge\";s:1:\"0\";s:29:\"package_room_total_surcharges\";s:1:\"0\";s:18:\"package_hotel_name\";a:1:{i:0;s:12:\"PICNIC HOTEL\";}

Comment: Where/How do you get that serialized data?

Comment: I get all post data came from the other form. $prev_details = $_POST and i insert it into the textarea inside the form to pass it to the form that i will unserialize. Here is my text area <textarea name="step_booking_serialized"><?php echo serialize($prev_details); ?></textarea>

Comment: When i pass it to the other form it will get the value. but when i tag it unserialize nothing happens